# Expected one matching request for criteria on delete method

Tags: angular, httpclient, karma-jasmine

I am writing a unit test for a method that uses the `delete` method of HttpClient in Angular. Normally, it can be pretty easy, but in this case, I am using parameters when I call the endpoint. So I am getting errors and I can't identify what's the problem.

When I run the test I get those errors.
[image]

This is my Angular method.

```
  delete(pr1: string, pr2: string) {
    const params = new HttpParams()
      .set('param1', pr1)
      .set('param2', pr2)

    const url = `${endpointUrl}​/data/${pr2}`;
    return this.http.delete(url, {params});
  }
```

Then, this is my unit test:

```
import {HttpClient, HttpParams, HttpRequest} from '@angular/common/http';
import {HttpClientTestingModule, HttpTestingController, TestRequest} from '@angular/common/http/testing';
import {TestBed} from '@angular/core/testing';

import {MyCustomService} from './eared-dove.service';

describe('MyCustomService', () => {
  let service: EaredDoveService;
  let httpMock: HttpTestingController;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        HttpClientTestingModule,
      ]
    });
    service = TestBed.inject(EaredDoveService);
    httpMock = TestBed.inject(HttpTestingController);
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    httpMock.verify();
  });

  it('should be created', () => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  });

  describe('delete()', () => {
    it('should call delete method of httpclient', () => {
      const mockPr1 = 'a-uuid';
      const mockPr2 = 'b-uuid';

      const params = `param2=${mockPr2}&param1=${mockPr1}`;
      const url = `${endpointUrl}/data​/${mockPr2}?${params}`;

      service.delete(mockPr1, mockPr2).subscribe()
      const request = httpMock.expectOne( (req: HttpRequest<any>)  => req.urlWithParams === url).flush(null);
    });
  });
});
```

Can you help me reviewing what Is going wrong in this test case?

Comment: u can log req.urlWithParams and see what is happening

Comment: @PetrAveryanov, I put a console.log for both values, `req.urlWithParam`, and `url` and both are the same.  `http://localhost:8080/data/param2?param2=pr2&param1=pr1`

Comment: An additional point is that if I compare those values in chrome console watcher the string values are the same but the length of them shows different values by one character.